# Rails calling freeze constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to do some code refactor inside of my webhook manager class. The idea was to use Builder pattern (hope I didn't get the names wrong) in which one class would distribute assignments to the others. That's why I build a class with constant variable `WEBHOOK_DEFINITIONS` and, depending on the arguments provided, would trigger the appropriate ActiveJob's. Like below:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ManageWebhookData
  WEBHOOK_DEFINITIONS = {
    default: IdentityChecks::IdentityCheckUpdaterJob,
    #there will be much more
    (...)
  }.freeze.with_indifferent_access

  def initialize(webhook, name)
    @webhook = webhook
    @name = name
  end

  def call
    WEBHOOK_DEFINITIONS[type].perform_later(webhook)
  end

  attr_reader :webhook, :name

  private

  def type
    WEBHOOK_DEFINITIONS.key(name.downcase) ? name.downcase : :default
  end
end
```

I don't know why but Rails somehow call `WEBHOOK_DEFINITIONS` even when it's `freeze` because I'm getting an error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant IdentityCheckUpdaterJob):
app/services/manage_webhook_data.rb:5:in `<class:ManageWebhookData>'
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's not rails, it's ruby.

Constants are resolving on class load, you could check it yourself in console

```
> class Foo
>   BAR = puts("I'm constant")
> end
I'm constant
```

Besides that, I'm not sure when Indifferent hash is called on freezed hash, it will be freezed too. I'd write instead

```
WEBHOOK_DEFINITIONS = {
    default: IdentityChecks::IdentityCheckUpdaterJob,
    #there will be much more
    (...)
  }.with_indifferent_access.freeze
```